# ¿Cómo puedo descargar una tabla de Bootstrap 5 a Excel con estilos?

Tags: php, bootstrap, excel

resulta que tengo diferentes tablas en Datatables-net y Tabulator.info puestas en mi desarrollo web, pero, me gustaría saber si hay una posibilidad de descargar este tipo de tablas en un archivo excel pero con las siguientes características:

- Que si mi tabla tiene los Headers de la tabla en color verde y con negrilla se descargue un archivo excel con el mismo estilo y que no sea plano.
- Que si mi tabla tiene el atributo de Stripped entonces que en el Excel se descargue las filas de esa misma manera.
- Y que si mi tabla tiene bordes cuando descargue el archivo Excel se descargue con los bordes de la tabla en excel.

Para que se entienda mucho más esta necesidad pondré imágenes de como quiero que funcione:

[image: Tabla de Tabulator con cabecera oscura, letra blanca y bordes]

Y como se descarga en el Excel:

[image: Como se ve en Excel]

Entonces me gustaría que se descargara así:

[image: Como me gustaría que descargara]

Entonces me gustaría saber como puedo hacer que esto suceda, la tabla de tabulator.info utiliza sheet.js para descargar el Excel, pero en sí no tiene la forma de modificar los estilos de las hojas de Excel, he revisado algunas tablas de pago y en estas si funciona como le dan estilos a las tablas y tal cual se descargan en Excel.

No se si puedan ayudarme, si se logra o hay algún tutorial, código o plugin, lo que sea seria de gran ayuda.

Muchísimas Gracias por la atención y saludo y suerte en todos sus proyectos...

Comment: Hola jose, hay varias librerias que te permiten crear archivos `.xlsx` como lo estas buscando, el detalle es que para eso necesitas obtener informacion por parte del servidor, tendrias que crear un script que te permita realizar la creacion de la tabla que quieres con todos los parametros. Si estas obteniendo la informacion de una base de datos pues es mas facil aun. aqui te dejo una libreria que puede ser de tu interes. [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)